# UITextView contentInset default animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uikit, uitextview

I have this code to adjust UITextView when keyboard is about to be displayed.

```
  @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let rectValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
    let keyboardSize = rectValue.cgRectValue.size
      
      let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
      
      textView.contentInset = contentInsets
      textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
     
  }
}
```

I see setting `contentInset` automatically creates a scrolling animation (after the keyboard appears fully) that makes the text at the cursor visible. The animation happens automatically and there is no way to disable it. I want to scroll to a given location in the textView sometimes when the keyboard is presented (preferably, animating it along with keyboard appearance). The implicit `contentInset` animation makes it impossible however. First the keyboard animates, then `contentInset` animates, and now only can I animate to my chosen location in textView. This is awkward. I am wondering what is the right way to achieve it?

Comment: There is no "implicit contentInset animation". The text view simply scrolls to reveal the current insertion point (selection). If you select some other text, the text view will scroll to it.

Comment: Hmm, but that default scrolling animation is causing trouble for me as explained in the question. What is the solution I wonder. In other words, how do I animate to my selectedRange along with keyboard appearance animation?